# How to add an icon to a script registered as a class?

Tags: godot

While learning Godot, the tutorial dictates how to add an icon to a class.

[Tutorial](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#register-scripts-as-classes)

> You may add a comma and an optional path to an image to use as an icon. You will then find your new type in the Node or Resource creation dialog.

Steps taken:

1. Added a 16x16 svg file to the resources named **something.svg**  .
   [image: resource pane]
2. Created a script with a path to that icon.
   [image: Scripts view]
3. Added a node of that kind.

[image: Nodes]

I don't see that icon? Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

For Godot 3.2.2, saving the scene and reloading the project should fix the issue.